# download kernel sources 3.19.0-69.77

Tags: drivers, kernel, source-code

I am developing a kernel module on top of ubuntu 14.04 LTS 3.19.0-69-generic codename trusty.
I need to download kernel sources in order for my compilation.
I cant find a proper package via the apt-cache, i downloaded:

```
linux-image-3.19.0-69-generic
linux-headers-3.19.0-69-generic
```

These packages does not contain the kernel sources.

Where do i get kernel source for this version ?
Do i need to download the kernel source for 3.19 and then compare ??  https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/3.19.0-69.77

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about

```
apt-get source <package>
```

Here is complete tutorial how to build your own kernel https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile

You also don't need full kernel sources to build out of tree kernel module
https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/build-linux-kernel-module-against-installed-kernel-source-tree.html

Comment: Hi, actually i do need the complete kernel source, i just tried the apt-get source and it worked, apt-get source linux-image-3.19.0-69-generic resulted in code being downloaded to /home/XXXX/linux-lts-vivid-3.19.0  - i guess i need to manually copy it to /usr/src/..